# Simple image listview NullPointerException error

Tags: android, android-listview

i am trying to create a simple listview that uses custom images and strings from a string array, however when i come to run it it gives a null pointer exception, saying that storage = null. I am not sure what is going on, i have triple checked all the spelling of the images etc... and cant find anything maybe its being caused within the code?

For the images i created a new directory in the res folder called drawable and put them in there, i have also added them to the other drawable folders just to be safe.

Here is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
```

Here is the main activity

```
   package com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView list;
    String[] memeTitles;
    String[] memeDescriptions;
    int[] memeImages = {R.drawable.meme1, R.drawable.meme2, R.drawable.meme3, R.drawable.meme4, R.drawable.meme5, R.drawable.meme6, R.drawable.meme7, R.drawable.meme8, R.drawable.meme9, R.drawable.meme10,R.drawable.meme1, R.drawable.meme2, R.drawable.meme3, R.drawable.meme4, R.drawable.meme5, R.drawable.meme6, R.drawable.meme7, R.drawable.meme8, R.drawable.meme9, R.drawable.meme10};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        Resources res = getResources();
        res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        lvAdapter adapter = new lvAdapter(this, memeTitles, memeImages, memeDescriptions);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

class lvAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    int size=1;
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArray;
    lvAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] descriptions){

        super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView, titles);
        this.context = c;
        this.images=imgs;
        this.titleArray = titles;
        this.descriptionArray = descriptions;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Converts the xml based single row into a java based view that we can manipulate and use
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
        TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);





        return row;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else

Thanks

EDIT

Here is the entire logcat for the exception

```
    07-27 10:15:03.466    1261-1261/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-27 10:15:04.056    1261-1261/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-27 10:15:04.056    1261-1261/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416e8ba8)
07-27 10:15:04.076    1261-1261/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview, PID: 1261
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
            at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
            at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:141)
            at com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview.lvAdapter.<init>(MyActivity.java:67)
            at com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 10:15:10.186    1261-1261/com.whosaidthat.endos.customimagelistview I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1261 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you will need to attach the entire logcat of the exception, this data is not sufficient for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are null when you send them to the Adapter

```
String[] memeTitles;
String[] memeDescriptions;
```

i guess you forget to  do this :

```
String[] memeTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
String[] memeDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
```

Comment: Shocking, cant believe i missed that, works perfect now, thanks a lot